# jQuery function won't apply to specific elements?

Tags: jquery

My function won't apply on element `a.left`, can anyone tell me why this is?

```
<section class="slideshow-control" style="">
    <a class="left" href="#">
        <span>«</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right" href="#">
        <span>»</span>
    </a>    
</section>
```

```js
var sc = sc.find('.slideshow-control');
var sw = sc.find('.slideshow-wrapper');

sc.find('a.left').click(function() {
    var swl = Math.min(0, parseInt(sw.css('left')) + sesw);
    sw.animate({ 'left': swl }, 800, 'easeInOutCirc');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You cannot animate `left` property of an element with position static, maybe that's why, who knows?... Anyway, you have to provide MCVE

Comment: Can you represent this problem at JSFiddle?

Comment: You aware there is no element with class `slideshow-wrapper` as decendant of `.slideshow-control`, right?! And `var sc = sc.find('.slideshow-control');` doesn't really make sense. In fact, many things are wrong with your question

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rhhy9ggz/

Comment: A. wolf -> Yes, i am aware of .slideshow-control, but i dont know, why function dont apply on element a.left ?

Comment: Does it enter the function ? You can't move an inline style. It needs, for instance, position:absolute set.

Comment: Other than that you don't show enough code, what is sesw? Maybe its undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There are some error in your code, some variable are missing.
If i undertand the behavuor of you script the following jsfiddle should work:

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhhy9ggz/2/)

You need to set 2 things and review your html:

```
<section class="slideshow-wrapper" style="">
  <section class="slideshow-control" style="">
    <a class="left" href="#"><span>«</span></a>
    <a class="right" href="#"><span>»</span></a>
  </section>
</section>
```

add this css so the element can have apply left propery animation:

```
.slideshow-wrapper {
  position:relative;
  left: 0;
}
```

left and right css property works on relative/absolute positioned element.

than run the js:

```
var sc = $('.slideshow-control');
var sw = $('.slideshow-wrapper');

sc.find('a.left').click(function() {
    moveBy = parseInt(sw.css("left"))-100;
    if(moveBy >= 0)
        sw.animate({ 'left': moveBy });
    return false;
});
sc.find('a.right').click(function() {
    moveBy = parseInt(sw.css("left"))+100;
    if(moveBy < $(document).width())
        sw.animate({ 'left': moveBy }, 'easeInOutCirc');
    return false;
});
```

i have add some control to prevent the element disappear out of the document.
You can start from this and add some other variable or rewrite it with your behaviours.